# Python's UDP crashes when sending to ip/port that isn't listening

Tags: python, sockets, server, crash, udp

If you send a UDP packet to a random ip/port that isn't listening, python closes the server that sent it (resulting in a crash)?

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Example of issue:

```
import socket

# Launch the server
try:
    Sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    Sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 25565))
except:
    print("Failed to launch server")

# Send a packet to a random (closed) place
# Comment out this line to prevent error
Sock.sendto(b'', ("127.0.0.1", 4623))


while True:
    # Wait for data
    print("Listening for data")
    data, addr = Sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

error:

> line 18, in 
>       data, addr = Sock.recvfrom(1024)
>   ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recvfrom` can fail, even on an UDP socket. This can be done for example if the previous send tried to send a packet to a system where nobody was listening on the port and the receiver send back an ICMP unreachable.

Your server only crashes because you don't expect `recvfrom` to fail, i.e. did not wrap it into a try-block as you did with the `bind`. If you catch the expected error using such block the server will not crash but properly handle the error.

Comment: That fixed it! I think that example is exactly what is happening here. Why does the ICMP unreachable cause receive to fail? How can I write code that detects that (other than try:except?) Is that the only way recvfrom can fail? Why didn't I read about this in the documentation? Looking at the wikipedia page for IMCP, there are a lot of error types. Are they the same in python? Sorry for so many questions, thank you for fixing!

Comment: @Andev: answering all these additional questions are out of context of the original one. There are more ways why and how recvfrom might fail, some of these depend on the OS. I suggest that you study the documentation of the native functions used by Pythons recvfrom, i.e. [recvfrom(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom), [recv(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recv). And about all these ICMP and similar stuff you might study [Advanced Network Programming](https://www.google.de/search?q=advanced+network+programming)

Comment: Thank you! I haven't come across that website before, so I'll have a look!